# Get (last) CUPS printer error programmatically

Tags: printing

I am setting up an unattended, automated printing setting. At some point the printer might run out of paper, ink, or experience some other error. I have a Canon iP4500 which on macOS communicates these kinds of errors back to the user interface. With Ubuntu/Lubuntu I have not seen such an interface.

**Is there any way to get the (last) CUPS error programmatically?**
I've tried

- `lpstat -p`
  (which will say something like "Printing page 1, 36%" when there is no paper)
- `lpc status`
- `lpq`
  (which says "iP4500-series is ready and printing")
- and dug around http://localhost:631/printers/Canon-iP4500-series, i.e. the CUPS web interface

I really don't care how "programmatically" is implemented, i.e. Python, Bash, parsing the CUPS web interface -- anything really. It just needs to be automated.

Answer (score 0):

For python, there is the **pycups** lib. I needed to install libcups2-dev (on Debian 9) to successfully install and compile it. The PyPi page example (https://pypi.org/project/pycups/) is pretty straightforward:

```
import cups
conn = cups.Connection ()
printers = conn.getPrinters ()
for printer in printers:
    print printer, printers[printer]["device-uri"]
```

For what you need, I believe that the relevant info is:

printer-info: Printer name

printer-state: numeric representation of the state.

printer-state-message: a string, informing the state.

printer-state-reasons: a list of strings.

Comment: This sounds like a solution, but all I get is `'printer-state': 4, 'printer-state-message': 'Printing page 1, 36%', 'printer-state-reasons': ['none']` -- which is the same as `lpstat -p` unfortunately. (I took the paper out of the printer, and the printer's status light flashes in the corresponding pattern.)